# Sort a 2D array in C++ using built in functions(or any other method)?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array like below. ( `array[5][2]` )

```
20  11    
10  20
39  14
29  15
22  23
```

after sorting it should be like below.

```
10  20
20  11
22  23
29  15
39  14
```

that means the array should be sorted comparing the first column values only.

In Java there is a built in function capability to do that. like below.

```
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Long[]>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Long[] o1, Long[] o2) {

                Long t1 = o1[1];
                Long p1 = o1[0];
                Long t2 = o2[1];
                Long p2 = o2[0];

                if (t1 == t2) {
                    return (p1 > p2 ? 1 : (p1 == p2 ? 0 : -1));
                } else {
                    return (t1 < t2 ? -1 : 1);
                }

            }
        });
```

So is there any C++ built in function capability to do these kind of stuff or how can i do this in C++ (the fastest implementation) ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did you declare array[5][2]. are they  just int's or did you use a STL container like std::vector, std::array ect...?

Comment: As odd as it sounds, `std::qsort()` may be an easier built-in to wedge-fit into a classic 2D array when sorting by single column.

Comment: `std::sort` accepts a comparator as the third argument. Any `op` such that `op(a,b)` means `a < b` is fine – function, lambda, functor object. Due to inlining, it’s usually faster than `qsort` with the same function, too.

Comment: I have seen the solutions and all of them transform the problem to solve it (std::array, std::vector, std::map) . Is there no way of sorting with 2d-array? After all, pointers can be iterators. Offhand I don't see a solution as the innermost dimension is an array and arrays are not assignable.arrays embedded in a struct are.

Answer (score 16):

I'm offering this up only because it was one of the few things `std::qsort` does *well* that `std::sort` simply does not, namely sort multi-column fixed arrays: The comparator is a string of ternary statements, but should be clear enough if you stare at it long enough:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int ar[10][2];

    // populate with random data
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,20);
    std::for_each(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar),
        [&](int (&ar)[2]){ ar[0] = dist(rng); ar[1] = dist(rng); });

    std::cout << "Before Sort..." << '\n';
    std::for_each(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar),
        [](const int(&ar)[2]) { std::cout << ar[0] << ',' << ar[1] << '\n';});

    std::qsort(ar, 10, sizeof(*ar),
        [](const void *arg1, const void *arg2)->int
        {
            int const *lhs = static_cast<int const*>(arg1);
            int const *rhs = static_cast<int const*>(arg2);
            return (lhs[0] < rhs[0]) ? -1
                :  ((rhs[0] < lhs[0]) ? 1
                :  (lhs[1] < rhs[1] ? -1
                :  ((rhs[1] < lhs[1] ? 1 : 0))));
        });

    std::cout << "After Sort..." << '\n';
    std::for_each(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar),
        [](const int(&ar)[2]) { std::cout << ar[0] << ',' << ar[1] << '\n';});

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run** (yours will vary, obviously)

```
Before Sort...
2,11
18,4
20,20
14,6
8,10
17,8
14,14
3,10
20,14
19,19
After Sort...
2,11
3,10
8,10
14,6
14,14
17,8
18,4
19,19
20,14
20,20
```

Notes: this specifically uses strict-value comparison rather than subtraction short-cuts in the comparator so as to avoid potential underflow issues. If that is not a problem in your restricted data-space, you could easily make that comparator significantly simpler.

Comment: Why the code will give `error C2664: 'qsort' : cannot convert parameter 4 from '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda2>' to 'int (__cdecl *)(const void *,const void *)'` under VS?

Comment: Why do you think `std::sort(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), [](int const (&ar)[2])->bool{…}` wouldn’t work just as well?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Have you *tried* it? `std::sort` uses move and value assignment, and fixed C arrays are not assignable by-value (though they can be initialized). So to answer the question you posed, because it wouldn't work at all, therefore it wouldn't work as well.

Comment: @herohuyongtao That would be the fault of MS, but you can get around it by moving the lambda to its own static function. the rest would be the same.

Comment: @WhozCraig No C++ on my iPad, sorry. :-) But you’re right, of course – while fixed C arrays have the minor advantage that we *know* their layout (in all practical situations), they don’t behave properly in the world of C++. And with any half-decent compiler, a simple `std::pair<int,int>` or custom class w/o virtuals doesn't take more space either, so there’s really little reason to use them in the first place.

Comment: I've up-voted this answer, because I believe `qsort` is the correct answer, but I've replaced your lambda in my answer with one capable of coping with variably sized arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38249167/2642059

Answer (score 12):

The built-in arrays of C and C++ are very inflexible, among other things they cannot be assigned.

Your best option would be the 'array' class from the C++ standard library, at least for the inner dimension:

```
array<int, 2> a[5] = { { 20, 11 },
{ 10, 20 },
{ 39, 14 },
{ 29, 15 },
{ 22, 23 } };

sort( a, a + 5 );
```

### Edit:  Some more explanations.

Here we use the property of std::array that '<' by default compares them lexicographically, i.e. starts with the first element.  In order to sort things differently we have to come up with an comparator object, so if you want to use the second column as sort key you have to do this:

```
auto comp = []( const array<int, 2>& u, const array<int, 2>& v )
      { return u[1] < v[1]; };
sort( a, a + 5, comp );
```

And as mentioned in the first comment, `sort(a, a+5 ...` is just an ugly short form for the cleaner `sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a) ...`

Comment: use `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)` instead of `a` and `a + 5`.

Comment: How about sorting based on the second elements?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: `sort( a, a + 5, []( array<int, 2>& u, array<int, 2>& v ){ return u[1] < v[1]; } );`

Answer (score 6):

First off, if you'd given `vector<vector<int>> array` this would be sortable just using: `sort(begin(array), end(array))` because `vector` defines lexicographic comparison functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

That said, there are drawbacks to using a `vector`-of-`vector`s: [What are the Issues with a vector-of-vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38244435/2642059) and it's clearly not what you intended. Given `int array[5][2]` trying to use [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) will yield:

> error C3863: array type 'int [2]' is not assignable

Instead of using `swap` to exchange 2 `int[2]`s we need to simply need to swap bytes of `sizeof(*array)`, that can be accomplished using [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) as suggested by [WhozCraig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20932034/2642059), but we can improve upon that making our comparator capable of handling any size sub-array. Given `int array[5][2]` or whatever dimensions are desired we can write:

```
static const auto SIZE = size(*array);   

qsort(array, size(array), sizeof(*array), [](const auto lhs, const auto rhs) {
    const auto first = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(lhs);
    const auto last = next(first, SIZE);
    const auto its = mismatch(first, last, reinterpret_cast<const int*>(rhs));

    if (its.first == last) {
        return 0;
    } else if (*its.first < *its.second) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }});
```

A quick note `array` should not be used as a variable name as it defines a standard type, with this change you can find an example here: http://ideone.com/87AoIr

Comment: Nice answer. Note that most of the drawbacks of vector of vectors go away in the OP's specific case of fixed arrays with C++11 and beyond. Indeed, `std::array<std::array<int, M>, N>` with `N` and `M` being rows and columns respectively, would work wonderfully with `std::sort`. If the outer dimension is potentially unruly, a vector of arrays would still work well.

Comment: @WhozCraig Just took me 2 years to write it after reading your answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, since you have only two `ints` in your second dimension, I would use instead an array of pairs, which have their own built in comparison function. With something like `pair<int,int> arr[200]`, you would be able to call the built in sort function `sort(arr, arr + 200)`, which would sort your array by first element, and then by the second element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // pair of integers
    pair<int, int> arr[1000];

    // fill array with random numbers
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 rng(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(0,1000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // make_pair(x, y) creates a pair with two integers x and y
        arr[i] = make_pair(uni(rng), uni(rng));
    }

    // prints out initial array
    cout << "BEFORE ARRAY..." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // .first and .second call the first and second ints in the pair respectively
        cout << arr[i].first << " " << arr[i].second << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // sort the array by calling built in sort function
    sort(arr, arr + 10);

    // prints out array
    cout << "FINAL ARRAY..." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << arr[i].first << " " << arr[i].second << endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

When you run this program, you see that the arrays are now sorted:

```
BEFORE ARRAY...
726 562
916 348
594 6
515 872
976 960
662 169
529 317
789 702
74 255
330 574

FINAL ARRAY...
74 255
330 574
515 872
529 317
594 6
662 169
726 562
789 702
916 348
976 960
```

Note how the second elements are also sorted, but secondary to the

Answer (score 3):

If you can, use `Vector` with some struct to hold two `int`:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> pairType;
std::vector<pairType> vec;

// Initialize vector

std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [](pairType& first, pairType& second)->bool { return first.first < second.first });
```

Answer (score 3):

We can simply use sort on row or column basis using inbuilt sort function in c++.
We have to just pass compare function with proper arguments.

Here is an example of sorting 2D array column wise.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool compare(int *a, int *b){
    // sorting on basis of 2nd column
    return a[1] < b[1];
}

void sorting(int **arr,int n){
    //calling in built sort
    sort(arr, arr + n, compare);
    // printing after sorting 
    cout<<"---------After Sorting---------"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout<<arr[i][0]<<" "<<arr[i][1]<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int **arr, i, n;
    cout<<"Enter the size of array  : ";
    cin>>n;
    //array of size arr[n][2]; 
    arr = new int*[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr[i] = new int[2];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i][0];
        cin>>arr[i][1];
    }
    
    sorting(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to sort a 2D array in time(using only columns) . . .will cost you reference locality... Else, every other way will involve lots of copying of rows.. . . Though (C++'s move operations may cushion this)

You would create a new array of pointers to a 2D array... Then sort the pointers...

Else, every other answer before mine seems good. But I advise you to use std::array.

Answer (score 0):

If end container doesn't matter, how about using a map ?

```
#include<map>

std::map<int, int> m;

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
    m[array[i][0]] = array[i][1] ;
```

You can now copy `m` back to your `array`

```
std::size_t  i=0;
for(const auto& x:m)
{   
    array[i][0] = x.first ;
    array[i++][1] = x.second ;
}
```

Comment: Just to point out that this only works if `array[i][0]` is unique (for all i).