# C programming. Sorting rows in a 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort the elements within the individual rows of a `2D` array. I understand how to sort the elements inside a `1D` array, but I am having serious trouble getting it to sort the `2D`.

Code for the `1D` array:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = i +1; j < size; ++j)
    {
        if (array2[i] > array2[j])
        {
            swap = array2[i];
            array2[i] = array2[j];
            array2[j] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

**What I want to do:** `2D` Array before sorting

```
9 2 0 1 6 3
0 9 1 2 3 8
4 2 5 4 3 6
3 6 4 3 9 3
0 2 1 2 0 4
4 1 9 4 2 7
```

`2D` array after sorting:

```
0 1 2 3 6 9
0 1 2 3 8 9
2 3 4 4 5 6
3 3 3 4 6 9
0 0 1 2 2 4
1 2 4 4 7 9
```

My code for the `2D` so far:

size: the user defined dimensions (in the above case it is 6)

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if(array[i][j] > array[i][j+1])
        {
            swap = array[i][j];
            array[i][j] = array[i][j+1];
            array[i][j+1] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: Could you run `qsort` over the rows or are you contractually obliged to use your own sort?

Comment: In your 1D example the `i` loop is wrong. It should be `for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++)` because `j` starts at `i + 1`. This error is also in your 2D example. Write a function that sorts a 1D array passed as an argument (with size). Then build on that to sort each array in your 2D example.

Comment: It appears to me a bubble sort assignment. Just make a function of the bubble sort (your code for 1 D array) and call it for each row of the 2D array

Comment: For C++ and Java this may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931669/sort-a-2d-array-in-c-using-built-in-functionsor-any-other-method

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use your single array sorting algorithm `(bubble sort)` to sort the two dimensional array then you have to add the another `for` loop: An outer `for` loop which will take care of each row. Let's say `m` is number of row and `n` is number of column.

```
for(k=0; k< m; k++) {
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     for (j = i +1; j < n; ++j) {
       if (array2[k][i] > array2[k][j])  {
           int swap = array2[k][i];
           array2[k][i] = array2[k][j];
           array2[k][j] = swap;
       }
     }
   } 
}
```

But this is not an efficient approach to sort the array, it's time complexity will be `O(mn^2)`

Comment: for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (j = i+1; j < size; ++j)
            {
                if (array[k][i] > array[k][j])
                {
                    swap = array[k][i];
                    array[k][i] = array[k][j];
                    array[k][j] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
    }
Working code. Thank you.

Comment: Yes,, in case you have row==column then its OK. :)

Answer (score 0):

copy all the elements of the 2d array into an 1d array
then apply any sorting algorithm on 1d array & then copy back the sorted 1d array to the 2d array.
please don't mind
if you have a better solution then post it that will be helpfull for me.

Comment: The question asks to sort _individual rows of a `2D` array_. This would just sort the `2D` array as if it was `1D` (it is, in memory). Also, there is no need to copy the array, bubble sort is in place - copying arrays is very expensive.

Comment: sir,
I have already made it clear that if you have any perfect logic to sort whole 2d array then please post it.
sorting n rows is equal to sorting n 1d arrays.
& i don't find sorting n rows helpfull because that's a very simple task.

Answer (score 0):

*You can simply use STL to sort 2D array row-wise..*

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for ( j=0;j<n;j++){
        cin>>a[i][j];
    }
    sort(a[i],a[i]+n);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int tmp,l;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        tmp = a[i][j];
        l = j + 1;
        for (int k = i; k < 2; k++) {
            while (l < 2) {
                if (tmp < a[k][l]) {
                    tmp = a[k][l];
                    a[k][l] = a[i][j];
                    a[i][j] = tmp;
                }
                l++;
            }
            l = 0;
        }
    }
}
```