# C++ sort matrix's row using STL

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, g++

Is it possible to sort matrix's row using STL `sort` in c++?

like we sort 1-dimensional array from index `x` to `y` like:

```
int a[100];
sort(a+x, a+y+1);
```

how can I call `sort` for `int a[100][100]` if I want so sort `i-th` row from `x` to `y`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931669/sort-a-2d-array-in-c-using-built-in-functionsor-any-other-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
std::sort(a[i] + x, a[i] + y + 1);
```

The `+ 1` is necessary because the end iterator must point 1 element after the last element of the row vector.

If you want to sort the whole row, you can do it more elegantly like

```
std::sort(std::begin(a[i]), std::end(a[i]));
```