# Using Sub-Vectors With qsort

Tags: c++, arrays, void-pointers, qsort, strict-aliasing

I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38249167/2642059) to use [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) to sort an array-of-arrays. I could not use [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on account of it's use of the assignment operator in `swap` operations.

I believe that the stipulation on my answer working is:

> The type of the elements of the array must be a [TrivialType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialType), otherwise the behavior is undefined

So my question is: **Is `int[2]` a "TrivialType"?**

---

The actual code in answer that prompted this question is:

```
int array[5][2] = { {20, 11}, {10, 20}, {39, 14}, {29, 15}, {22, 23} };
static const auto SIZE = size(*array);

qsort(array, size(array), sizeof(*array), [](const auto lhs, const auto rhs) {
    const auto first = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(lhs);
    const auto last = next(first, SIZE);
    const auto its = mismatch(first, last, reinterpret_cast<const int*>(rhs));

    if (its.first == last) {
        return 0;
    } else if (*its.first < *its.second) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }});
```

Comment: You needed to follow the links: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial: *that is, a scalar type, a trivially copyable class with a trivial default constructor, or array of such type/class, possibly cv-qualified*

Comment: IIRC you should prefer `std::sort()` over `qusort()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You read the question right? I explained right in the question why that wouldn't work.

Comment: If you replace the C arrays with `std::array` your problem disappears.

Comment: @nwp Or `vector` or any other container that is copy assignable. I mention that in my answer that prompted this question, but my intent here is to find out if this is legal for arrays.

Comment: @NathanOliver Your quote may answer my question but my understanding of how constructors and destructors pertain to built in types is too shaky for me to interpret it usefully. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `int` is a Arithmetic type per [basic.fundamental] and a Arithmetic type is also called a scalar type per [basic.types]/9

> Arithmetic types (3.9.1), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types (3.9.2), std::nullptr_-t, and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called *scalar types*.

and then we have

> Scalar types, trivial class types (Clause 9), **arrays of such types** and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively
>   called *trivial types*

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So an scalar type and an array of a scalar are both *trivial types*.

<sup>All quotes from draft N3797</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `int[2]` is a trivial type. From basic.types/9

> ... Scalar types, trivial class types (Clause [class]), **arrays of such
>   types** and cv-qualified versions of these types
>   ([basic.type.qualifier]) are collectively called trivial types. ...

And int is a scalar type.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is: **Is `int[2]` a "TrivialType"**?

Yes, it is.

You can easily check this, all the necessary tools are right at hand from [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[2];

    std::cout << "a is " << (std::is_trivial<decltype(a)>()?"":"non ") << "trivial" << std::endl;
}
```

outputs

```
a is trivial
```

See the [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44fc2bc7359c8308)

Comment: Ha, I feel a little bit dumb now... I'm guessing you didn't mean to include `iomanip`?

Comment: @JonathanMee _"I'm guessing you didn't mean to include iomanip?"_ Yes, I prematurely included it from the vision to output something like `true` or `false` and need to use `std::boolalpha`. I've seen much, much dumber questions here already BTW, don't worry.