# How to sort array of arrays by std::sort?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have such array:

```
long my_array_left[n][2];
```

I wrote comparator function for it, which takes array of two elements and sort by first element of array:

```
struct sort_left {
    bool operator()(const long &left[2], const long &right[2]) {
        return left[0] < right[0];
    }
}
```

Then I use library function `std::sort` for sorting `my_array_left[n][2]`

```
sort(begin(my_array_left), end(my_array_left), sort_left());
```

But I have an error:
`parameter type mismatch: Incompatible pointer types 'long **' and 'long[2]*'`.

How can I overcome it?

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931669/sort-a-2d-array-in-c-using-built-in-functionsor-any-other-method

Comment: Your compiler really said `long[2]*`?

Comment: @aschepler Exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem can be fixed by having a comparator that actually takes references to arrays instead of references to pointers:

```
struct sort_left {
    bool operator()(const long (&left)[2], const long (&right)[2]) {
        return left[0] < right[0];
    }
};
```

But since you can't assign an array to another array, your code won't compile anyway.

You can avoid this by using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
array<array<long, 2>, N> arr{};
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

The added benefit is that `operator<` is automatically defined if `array`'s `value_type` that defines it.

Comment: I did not know that `std::array` used as a `value_type` for `std::array` would be sortable. Neat! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a232eca55a5fa6cb

Comment: error: the value of ‘N’ is not usable in a constant expression
     array<array<long, 2>, N> arr;

Comment: Yes, you cannot have arrays of variable size in C++. If you're using it as a gcc extension, use `array<long, 2> arr[n]` and then `sort(arr, arr+n);`