# Merge Sort Using Vectors c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, merge, mergesort

I'm trying to sort a text file using the merge sort method using vectors instead of arrays. The code builds but when I run it I get a an out bounds error on one of my vectors.

Specifically :

```
for (int k = start; k < end; k++)
{
    if (L.at(x) <= R.at(y))
    {
        v.at(k) = L.at(x);          // out of bounds
        x++;
    }
    else
    {
        v.at(k) = R.at(y);          // out of bounds
        y++;
    }

}
```

I resize vector 'v' yet int K still increments to high. i.e. the size of v will be 10, yet k will also equal 10. I've tried changing some values, but every time it compiles the function ends up not sorting. I've looked up various methods of merge sort and each time I keep getting the same out of bounds error.

**EDIT:** I made a change to my loops, now it goes through my functions. But they return a blank vector. The entire 'v' vector is whitespace when I print it.

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std

vector<string> readFile(string fileName) {
    /* reads a textfile into vector. Works dandy. */ 
}

vector<string> merge(vector<string>& v, int start, int mid, int end) {
    int n1 = mid - start + 1;
    int n2 = end - mid;

    vector<string> L;
    vector<string> R;

    L.resize(n1 + 1); // size left vector
    R.resize(n2 + 1); // size right vector

    for (int i = 1; i < n1; i++) {
        L.at(i) = v.at(start + i - 1); // populate left vector
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < n2; j++) {
        R.at(j) = v.at(mid + j);       // populate right vector
    }

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

for (int k = start; k < end; k++)
{
    if (L.at(x) <= R.at(y))
    {
        v.at(k) = L.at(x);          // merge left vector into v
            if (x < L.size() - 1)   // prevents x from increasing past bounds of L vector
            x++;
    }
    else
    {
        v.at(k) = R.at(y);          // merge right vector into v
        y++;
    }
    return v;
}

vector<string> mergeSort(vector<string>& v, int start, int end) {
    int middle;
    if (start < end)                    // base case
    {
        middle = (start + end) / 2;     // find middle
        mergeSort(v, start, middle);    // divide vectors
        mergeSort(v, middle + 1, end);
        merge(v, start, middle, end);   // merge sorted vectors
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> vectorReadIn;
    vector<string> sortedVector;
    int x = 0;

    string fileName = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/Algorithims/Perm Words/perm15k.txt";

    vectorReadIn = readFile(fileName);    // reads file into vector

    sortedVector = mergeSort(vectorReadIn, 1, vectorReadIn.size());  // calls mergesort
    cout << "Sorted file:" << endl;
    while (x < 8) {
        cout << sortedVector.at(x);
        x++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a 2D array in C++ using built in functions(or any other method)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931669/sort-a-2d-array-in-c-using-built-in-functionsor-any-other-method)

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38249167/2642059 What you're looking for is `sort(begin(vectorReadIn), end(vectorReadIn))`.

Comment: I should clarify, I am comparing time complexities of various sorting algorithms and I am stuck on merge sort. I decided to use vectors since they can change dynamically and save me from using arrays.

Comment: If I may, the right tool for the job is almost always the one provided by the standard. Your issue here demonstrates the concept that as mere mortals you and I will very frequently make poor decisions even when implementing algorithms for comparison. If you're going to persist in this folly, at a minimum you should use the standard's [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) to exchange strings.

Answer (score 0):

All the indexing that you're doing on your `vectors` is 1-based.  C++ vectors (and arrays) use 0-based indexing.  At the very least, `x` and `y` should be initialized to 0, the indexing in the `i` and `j` population loops should start at 0 (with appropriate changes to the end condition and usage within the loop), and the second parameter in the call to `mergeSort` in `main` should be 0, not 1.

Comment: I made the changes and I got a little further. I was going off my teacher's pseudo code template. She probably accounted for it somewhere, and I missed it. Now my vector comes up back blank! I'll edit more info above.