# C++ Two Dimensional Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying make make a basic chunk loading system using two dimensional arrays, and PNG images. I was just wondering if it is possible to create a uninitialized array for example;

```
Chunk[][] chunks;
```

and then initialize it based on the size of the PNG image and use different rgb pixels to stand for different tiles.

Say the immage is 15x25, is it possible to initialize the two dimensional array with a somewhat like this?

```
chunks = new Chunk[15][25];
```

Or should I go about making a large array and just having the index's that aren't set be a VOID tile I could just simply make.

Thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new). I would recommend either using `std::array<std::array<Chunk, 15>, 25>` or following your own suggestion of a 15*25 1D array.

Comment: You could use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), `std::vector<std::vector<Chunk>> chunks(15, std::vector<Chunk>(25));`

Comment: `Chunk[][] chunks;` is not legal C++, all but the first dimension must be specified using a compile time constant. Use a vector (1D) or a vector of vectors (2D) anything but a 2D array.

Comment: `chunks = new Chunk[a][b]` is hard to achieve. The size of an array is constant, and should be defined at compile-time (though, GCC does have an expansion that allows a `const int` to determine the size). Reading this PNG image, or files in general, cannot occur at compile-time. Therefore, you should use other containers, such as `std::vector<T>`, where the size does not have to be predetermined.

Comment: Neither of those duplicates are correct, the problem calls for a contiguous block of memory with dynamic dimensions.

Comment: You can use this technique, basically a single dimension array with a two dimensional accessing scheme: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436723/sorting-2-d-array-in-c-using-inbuilt-stdsort-function/52436916#52436916

Comment: Another example of the technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53038618/3807729

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not support variable-length arrays like C does. Modern, idiomatic C++ also discourages raw arrays over `std::vector` or `std::array`, which can also be used in 2D, like so:

```
std::size_t x = /* get X dimension */
std::size_t y = /* get Y dimension */
std::vector<std::vector<Chunk>> chunks(x, std::vector<Chunk>(y));
```

`std::vector` also has the advantage of automatic size management and permissibility of a variable-length initializer, unlike `std::array`, which, to my knowledge, only permits constants during initialization.