# Solution of Two-dimensional array of sort in C++? And how sort be the fastest way to sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am a beginner of C++. I learned a function code `vector() name1;` and use `sort(name1.begin(), name1.end(), cmp)` to help sort my vector array. 
My teacher told me that sort is the fastest way to sort,but I want to know how and why.
The Final question is how to sort a two-dimensional array in the function code `sort`.

Comment: `std::sort` is not fastest, but is good enough on average and is asymptotically optimal. The question about sorting 2D arrays is asked here several times a week, please use search.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "sort a 2d array"? There are multiple things that can be called that. Are you free to move the inner elements to anywhere or do they have to stay together?

Answer (score 0):

std::sort is not the fastest sorting technique but yeah it's optimal and works for large range of inputs 
quick sort algorithm sorts the one dimensional vector in least time [click here to know how inbuilt sorting works](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-details-of-stdsort-in-c/)

For sorting a 2-D dimensional vector one has to specify whether to sort the elements in column-wise or row-wise,there is no inbuilt function for sorting 
You can see the previous threads on sorting a 2-D vector
[sorting of a 2-d vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931669/sort-a-2d-array-in-c-using-built-in-functionsor-any-other-method)