# Sort 2d C++ array by first element in subarray

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a c++ subarray by first element.
My code is currently set up like this:

```
int umbrellas[3][2] = {{5, 6}, {2, 7}, {9, 20}};

int n = sizeof(umbrellas) / sizeof(umbrellas[0]);

sort(umbrellas, umbrellas + n, greater<int>());
```

The sort function doesn't seem to be functioning properly and when I run the code it generates errors. Is there a way to sort the array from

```
{{5, 6}, {2, 7}, {9, 20}}
```

into

```
{{2, 7}, {5, 6}, {9, 20}}
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a 2D array in C++ using built in functions(or any other method)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931669/sort-a-2d-array-in-c-using-built-in-functionsor-any-other-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `std::vector` of `std::vector` as your container and the sort becomes much easier to do with. Not only is `std::vector` the preferred container for C++ but using STL functions on it is way simpler and direct , without any substantiable overhead.

Define your data as

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> umbrellas{
    {5, 6},
    {2, 7},
    {9, 20}
};
```

Now you can use a custom comparator lambda that takes in two vector element references and returns True when the first element of the above vector is smaller than that of the one below.

```
std::sort(umbrellas.begin(),
          umbrellas.end(),
          [](const std::vector<int> &above, const std::vector<int> &below)
          {
              return (above[0] < below[0]);
          });
```

And the output :

```
for (auto &&row : umbrellas) {
    for (auto element : row) {
        std::cout<< element<< " ";
    }
    std::cout<< "\n";
}
```

```
2 7 
5 6 
9 20
```

---

Taking this to C++20 it's even easier:

```
std::ranges::sort(umbrellas, std::less(),
     [](const auto &v) { return v[0];});
```

Answer (score 0):

If time complexity doesn't matter, this code will achieve the desired with O(n^2) complexity

```
int arr[3][2] = {{5, 6}, {2, 7}, {9, 20}};

int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

for(int i = 0 ; i < n - 1; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < n - 1 ; j++){
        if(arr[j][0] > arr[j + 1][0])
            swap(arr[j],arr[j + 1]);
    }
}
```