# Attempting to switch columns and rows in a 2d array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to switch the rows and columns for a 2d array.
For example:

```
[1,1,1]
[2,2,2]
[3,3,3]
```

goes to

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

However, my code returns the same 2d array as when it starts. Anyone know how to fix this?

Code:

```java
public static int[][] invert(int[][] array) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array[j].length / 2; i++) {
            int temp = array[j][i];
            array[j][i] = array[j][array[j].length - i - 1];
            array[j][array[j].length - i - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're transposing the matrix twice. You switch every position with its transpose position and then switch it back. Double check your loop bounds.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422374/multi-dimensional-array-transposing